# How do I ensure that the IME show/hide results in a call to View.onSizeChanged()

Tags: android

I have a `View` implementation whose parent layout is a `ScrollView`.  I would like to be called back when the IME is shown/hidden so that I can resize the `View` accordingly.  I understand that `onSizeChanged()` should be called each time the IME is shown or hidden, but in my code this is not happening.

I've written a test application in order to get the functionality I'm after, and it contains:

- A `Button` to toggle the IME (show/hide).
- A `ScrollView` containing several `TextView`s.

When I click on the button (in this test app), then the IME is shown and the `ScrollView` is resized accordingly.  This is the behaviour I want.  I note that in the test app, the `ScrollView`'s `onSizeChanged()` gets called by the framework requesting a layout, and then an `invalidate()` to redraw
the screen.  This behaviour is missing in my incorrectly-functioning application; there is no call to the `ScrollView`'s `onSizeChanged()` or to my implemented `View`'s `onSizeChanged()`.

My manifest contains the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` attribute, and I've also added `isScrollContainer="true"` to the `ScrollView`'s attribute in the layout xml, but this doesn't appear to make any difference.

Could someone please suggest what it is that I could look at in order to get the `onSizeChanged()` callback in my `View`?

---

Note: This is essentially a cross-post of the following on the Android-Developers group:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/t/fa84d7cb450c7f5e

Apologies if this offends anyone, but by posting here (with appropriate tags) I believe that the android team will see it and hopefully provide some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I've used the FULL_SCREEN Window flag.  That flag and adjustResize are 'incompatible' it seems.

This came up in August last year:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4f5f779d58170d20

Presumably, this is a defect and so I'll get around to raising an issue.